# How to Invert Bar Chart Direction to Upwards When Secondary Y-Axis Values Are Negative in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to create a dual-axis plot using ggplot2 where the primary y-axis displays a line chart representing 'Log Odds' with values ranging from 0 to -8, and the secondary y-axis displays a bar chart for 'Weighted Count'. The bar chart needs to show counts above the zero line, but due to the negative values on the primary y-axis, the bars are being plotted downwards.

Here's the challenge I am facing:

The line chart, which represents a 'Log Odds' metric, decreases downwards correctly, from 0 to -8. However, I want the bar chart to start at the equivalent of zero on this scale (the -8 mark on the line chart) and extend upwards as the count increases. The bars need to represent positive values even though they are aligned with a negative scale on the primary axis.

So far, I have attempted to use a transformation factor to align the two scales. I've tried normalizing the secondary axis based on the primary axis's range, and then applied an additional transformation factor to get the bars to start from zero and grow upwards. However, the bars continue to display as descending from the top of the plot area rather than ascending from the baseline of the line chart.

Here's what we've tried in our code:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Sample data
set.seed(123)
bucket_label <- seq(0, 2.5, by=0.5)
log_odds <- seq(-1, -8, length.out=length(bucket_label))
Count <- sample(100:1000, length(bucket_label), replace = TRUE)
BucketedData_nonmat <- data.frame(bucket_label, log_odds)
Count.1 <- data.frame(bucket_label, Count)

# Current plot code
fit_range <- range(BucketedData_nonmat$log_odds, na.rm = TRUE)
freq_range <- range(Count.1$Count, na.rm = TRUE)
transformation_factor <- (freq_range[2] / fit_range[2]) /8

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = Count.1, aes(x = bucket_label, y = Count / transformation_factor), stat = "identity", fill = "grey", color = "grey", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(data = BucketedData_nonmat, aes(x = bucket_label, y = log_odds), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Log Odds",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * transformation_factor, name = "Weighted Count")
  )
```

What I ultimately want is for the bars to be face upwards and to visually start from the end of the line chart, moving upwards, with both charts starting at the same baseline, even though one is effectively negative.

Has anyone encountered a similar challenge or have suggestions on how to achieve the desired result in ggplot2?

Here is what the current code produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`geom_tile` gives us more direct control at the cost of a little more legwork. Here, I define the

```
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = Count.1, 
           aes(x = bucket_label, width = 0.9*0.5,
               y =  -8 - (Count / transformation_factor) / 2,
               height = (Count / transformation_factor)),
           stat = "identity", fill = "grey", color = "grey", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(data = BucketedData_nonmat, aes(x = bucket_label, y = log_odds), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Log Odds",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. + 8) * - transformation_factor, name = "Weighted Count")
  )
```

[image]